# How to get the parent location in qweb odoo11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

How to get the parent location in qweb odoo11.

when i use `<t t-esc="o.location_id.name"/>` // didn't get the name of parent location.

I want the **parent location name**. Find the attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj8Nr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Get it working like this:

```
<t t-esc="o.location_id.complete_name"/>
```